# tesseract detect only one arabic word(instead of 28 characters) and digits

Tags: android, android-studio, ocr, tesseract, arabic

I'm working on a mobile application that will allow the user to capture a photo of a car plate and using the extracted string, it will look in a database for a matching car plate.
The problem is that the car plate has an arabic word in it since it will be used in an arab country and OCR doesn't provide a great result for this language so instead of looking for all arabic letters in the image, I thought of looking for specific characters (4 instead of 28).
Is that doable ? and does it give a better result ? and is it possible to detect both this specific string(the country name) and the digits in the car plate ?